# rails4 AR: Local var is declared in not executed code-block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In rails 4.2.5: Is it possible, that a locale var will be declared, even if it occurs in a not executed block?
See this example:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base

  def test

    # there is no local var `name`
    puts "name " + name.inspect
    puts "self.name " + self.name.inspect

    if false
      name = 'Hund'
    end

    # now there is a local var `name` (value `nil`)

    puts "name " + name.inspect
    puts "self.name " + self.name.inspect

  end
end
```

To test it:

```
>> Animal.new(:name=>'Katze').test

name "Katze"
self.name "Katze"
name nil
self.name "Katze"
```

We just were very surprised, that `name` suddenly was `nil`.

For which reason does it behave like this? Is this wanted behaviour? So we must not rely on `name`, but using `self.name` in future?

(No question, one should use `self.name = "Hund"`, but why is that local var declared.)

Thanks and regards, Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to realize that when you call `self.name` you're not actually accessing a variable but rather sending a message to an accessor method

```
def name
  @name
end
```

It's also important to know how the Ruby parser handles *local* variables, especially when inside a conditional. This is an excerpt from the **Well-Grounded Rubyist** Chapter 6.1.2

> When the Ruby parser sees the sequence identifier, equal-sign, value,
>   as in this expression
>
> ```
> x = 1
> ```
>
> it allocates space for a local variable called x. The creation of the
>   variable—not the assignment of a value to it, but the internal
>   creation of a variable—always takes place as a result of this kind of
>   expression, even if the code isn’t executed! Consider this example:
>
> ```
> if false
>   x = 1
> end
> p x # Output: nil
> p y # Fatal Error: y is unknown
> ```
>
> The assignment to x isn’t executed, because it’s wrapped in a failing
>   conditional test. But the Ruby parser sees the sequence  x = 1, from
>   which it deduces that the program involves a local variable x. The
>   parser doesn’t care whether x is ever assigned a value. Its job is
>   just to scour the code for local vari ables for which space needs to
>   be allocated. The result is that x inhabits a strange kind of variable
>   limbo. It has been brought into being and initialized to nil. In that
>   respect, it differs from a variable that has no existence at all; as
>   you can see in the example, examining  x gives you the value  nil,
>   whereas trying to inspect the non-existent variable y results in a
>   fatal error. But although x exists, it has not played any role in the
>   program. It exists only as an artifact of the parsing process.

Given the above information, the first time you call `name.inpspect` in your code, the Ruby parser knows that no such local variable has been defined so it looks to see whether a method by that name exists (it does as it's provided by ActiveRecord) and calls that method - so in the first case `name.inspect` and `self.name.inspect` are both calling the same accessor method.

The next time you call `name.inspect`, you're actually calling the local variable `name` which the Ruby parser has initialized to `nil`.

The takeaway is that you should always use `self` explicitly. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Ruby thing, not a Rails thing.

Ruby does not define a closed scope for `if` blocks.

You can get more details of the reason here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/why-if-statements-do-not-introduce-scope-in-ruby-1-9#answer-60413